# Understanding for the use of the & Bitwise Operator

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I have been analyzing a code and trying to understanding each part of the algorithm.
I came across this part where the bitwise and operator was used

```
if (qpd >= 0) qpd += qpd&1;
else qpd -= qpd&1;
```

From what I understand, the algorithm wants to use the 1 as a mask for the variable qpd but since the number is just 1, there's not much sense in doing an operation that virtually does not make any changes. Please enlighten me here since I'm lost.

The foor loop, which gets the magnitude and frequency of the data from an array, that uses the bitwise operator is as follows:

```
/* this is the analysis step */
            for (k = 0; k <= fftFrameSize2; k++) {

                /* de-interlace FFT buffer */
                real = gFFTworksp[2*k];
                imag = gFFTworksp[2*k+1];

                /* compute magnitude and phase */
                magn = 2.*sqrt(real*real + imag*imag);
                phase = atan2(imag,real);

                /* compute phase difference */
                tmp = phase - gLastPhase[k];
                gLastPhase[k] = phase;

                /* subtract expected phase difference */
                tmp -= (double)k*expct;

                /* map delta phase into +/- Pi interval */
                qpd = tmp/M_PI;
                if (qpd >= 0) qpd += qpd&1;
                else qpd -= qpd&1;
                tmp -= M_PI*(double)qpd;

                /* get deviation from bin frequency from the +/- Pi interval */
                tmp = osamp*tmp/(2.*M_PI);

                /* compute the k-th partials' true frequency */
                tmp = (double)k*freqPerBin + tmp*freqPerBin;

                /* store magnitude and true frequency in analysis arrays */
                gAnaMagn[k] = magn;
                gAnaFreq[k] = tmp;

            }
```

Comment: "virtually does not make any changes" makes no sense. It does make a change in some cases. There's nothing virtual about it.

Comment: Oh sorry Mat! What I mean by does not make any changes is that it would seem to not make any changes when I read it from my understanding of the & bitwise operator. Finally understood it from the answer below. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is used to round numbers to next even value; rounding positive numbers up and negative numbers down: for example

```
7 becomes 8
12 remains 12
-7 becomes -8
```

it works by adding or subtracting the last bit of the value that is 1 for odd numbers or 0 for even numbers.

Comment: Thank you 6402! I'm very much grateful for your help! I never knew that & can be used like this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3160974: It's 6502, not 6402!!!. I've no idea what a 6402 is... 6502 is the name of the first micro I used (8-bit, Apple ][).

Comment: Oh sorry 6502!!! That was really careless of me for that typo! I deeply apologize. Thank you again for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not entirely sure what all that is doing as a whole but all the `&` operator is doing is basically either adding one or zero, if the `qbd` is above or equal to zero, or subtracting one or zero (all based on what the first bit is) if it is less than zero.

Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Josh! Yeah that's the answer I was looking for. I was confused on my understanding about the & bitwise operator and now my understanding has been clarified. :)